# print array values in new format in array

Tags: php, jquery

I want to send the value to jquery-variable in new format, i am using nested foreach loop
here is my code:

```
    foreach($names as $key1 => $desc1) {
        $arr_names[] = $names;
        $details = get_details( $key1 );
           if ( is_array( $states ) ) {
          foreach($details as $key2 => $desc2) {
          $title[] = $key2;
          $value[] = $desc2;
          } 
          } 
    }
echo "<input type='hidden' id='storageElement' data-storectrystts='".json_encode($namdetailsArray)."'>";
```

Right now, i can get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sam
    [1] => Ben
    [2] => John

    [0] => Age
    [1] => Place
    [2] => Height
    [3] => Weight
    [4] => Year
    [5] => Salary

    [0] => 30
    [1] => AU
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 150
    [4] => First
    [5] => 50000
)
```

I need to send value in this format through data-storectrystts='".json_encode($namdetailsArray).":

```
'Sam' => [
    ['Age', '30'],
    ['Place', 'AU']],
'Ben' => [
    ['Height', '6'],
    ['Weight', '150']],
'John' => [
    ['Year', 'First'],
    ['Salary', '50000']]
```

> **Update**

```
//if we use print_r($namdetailsArray); then everything is fine

Array
(
    [Sam] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Age
                    [1] => 30
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Place
                    [1] => AU
                )
        )

    [Ben] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Height
                    [1] => 6
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Weight
                    [1] => 150
                )
        )
    [John] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Year
                    [1] => First
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Salary
                    [1] => 50000
                )
        )
    [Derek] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => tax's cal
                    [1] => 100
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => distance
                    [1] => 5
                )
        )
)



//if we use echo json_encode($namdetailsArray) then everything is fine
{"Sam" => [
    ["Age", "30"],
    ["Place", "AU"]],
"Ben" => [
    ["Height", "6"],
    ["Weight", "150"]],
"John" => [
    ["Year", "First"],
    ["Salary", "50000"]],
"Derek" => [
    ["tax's cal", "100"],
    ["distance", "5"]]}



/*but if we use 
echo "<input type='hidden' id='storageElement' data-storectrystts='".json_encode($namdetailsArray)."'>"; 
echo '<div id="availhai"></div>';

var cSttArry = $("#storageElement").data('storectrystts');
$("#availhai").html(cSttArry);
then it is not showing anything after word "tax" */

{"Sam" => [
    ["Age", "30"],
    ["Place", "AU"]],
"Ben" => [
    ["Height", "6"],
    ["Weight", "150"]],
"John" => [
    ["Year", "First"],
    ["Salary", "50000"]],
"Derek" => [
    ["tax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating lots of separate arrays. Create a single associative array where the key is the name, and the value is a 2-dimensional array like you show.

```
$namdetailsArray = array();
foreach ($names as $name => $desc) {
    $personArray = array();
    foreach ($desc as $key => $value) {
        $personArray[] = array($key, $value);
    }
    $namdetailsArray[$name] = $personArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, it is working but having an issue with the inverted comma in a value of array. one of the value is having inverted comma ([6] => tax's cal) so it got break on that value when i use json_encode.

Comment: `json_encode()` should take care of proper encoding of quotes. The problem is presumably with how you're using the values after you decode them.

Comment: For now i am just printing the array with php and through jquery:
if i use print_r($namdetailsArray) or echo json_encode($cntrySttArry); then everything is fine but if i get value though jquery then it got break on on the value of inverted comma, please see the Update section above.

Comment: If you're putting it inside an HTML attribute, use `htmlspecialchars(json_encode($namdetailsArray))`

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` will convert quotes to HTML entities.

Comment: tried this: echo "<input type='hidden' id='storageElement' data-storectrystts='".htmlspecialchars(json_encode($namdetailsArray))."'>"; still not working.

Comment: It should work. When you do `View Source`, do you see the inverted commas or are they converted to `&apos;`?

Comment: when i do view source then it is showing inverted comma, see here----------&quot;Derek&quot;:[[&quot;tax's cal&quot;, &quot;100&quot;],[&quot;distance", &quot;5&quot;]],

Comment: Ahh, you need the `ENT_QUOTES` flag to make it encode both single and double quotes. By default it only encodes double quotes. I wonder why you couldn't find that in the documentation?

Comment: actually i found it in documentation and tried it before but it do not show anything after using this:
echo "<input type='hidden' id='storageElement' data-storectrystts='".htmlspecialchars(json_encode($namdetai‌​lsArray), ENT_QUOTES)."'>";

Comment: Are there any warnings in the log?

Comment: but if i do view source it is showing &#039; for inverted comma.

Comment: That's what should be expected. Then when the HTML is parsed into the DOM, it should be decoded into a quote (sorry, we don't say "inverted comma" over here).

Comment: oh my mistake, but Barmar, if i use ENT_QUOTES then result is empty(nothing) on page. if i do view source then it is showing the code. i checked the log there is no warning.

Comment: it was not printing by using simple <div> but when i used in select then it is giving the list, perfect. Later i wanted to decode then i used $("<div/>").html(string).text(),
thanks a ton for your help, i was trying solve this since long, finally got it with htmlspecialchars(json_encode). Barmar, you are awesome man. Thanks again...